# How To Run Multiple .Net Projects With Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell-script, .net

I need to run multiple .net projects for a micro service based project so I written a simple .sh file to achieve this purpose.

```
#! /bin/sh.
~/start
dotnet run --project "AuthService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/FileUploadManagementService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/ContractFinancialManagementService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/ParameterManagementService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/ProcurementManagementService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/SiteManagementService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/StakeholderManagementService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/SupervisionManagementService/API" --no-build;
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/UserManagementService/API" --no-build;
```

My problem is after first line Auth service runs but no other projects start. How can I fix this?

Comment: Instead of `;` add this: `&` (in every line). For example: `dotnet run --project "AuthService/API" --no-build &`. This will run every command in background

Comment: Remove the trailing dot from the very first line. (There is no interpreter called `/bin/sh.` but there is one called `/bin/sh`)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon your solution works if you add it as an answer I would like to mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add `&` at the end of every line, this will run every command in background (I'm not sure what `~/start` does but it seems you do not need to add it the `&`).
Also as @roaima pointed out in the comments you will have to change `/bin/sh.` to (`/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` if you're working with `bash`).
So your code would become:

```bash
#! /bin/sh
~/start
dotnet run --project "AuthService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/FileUploadManagementService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/ContractFinancialManagementService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/ParameterManagementService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/ProcurementManagementService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/SiteManagementService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/StakeholderManagementService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/SupervisionManagementService/API" --no-build &
dotnet run --project "MicroServices/UserManagementService/API" --no-build &
```

I've also removed `;` from every line because it's not needed in your script since you are running every command in a new line. You only have to use `;` if you were running the commands on the same line: `command1;command2;etc`